# Why doesn't the render tree contain absolutely positioned elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

I was reading about render tree:

> While the DOM tree is being constructed, the browser constructs
>   another tree, the render tree. This tree is of visual elements in the
>   order in which they will be displayed. It is the visual representation
>   of the document. **Render tree does not contain `display:none`,
>   position absolute elements, HEAD.**

The last statement is a little confusing for me. Render tree contains visible elements. So, it should contain position absolute. How does the browser render these elements (`display:none`, position absolute elements, HEAD)? Can someone explain in more detail?

http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Comment: are they not there or are they invisible / positioned somewhere you dont expect.

Comment: `display: none;` Elements don't get rendered. `position: absolute` Elements are positioned independently to the rest of the tree so are probably put into their own tree and painted on top. `<head>` contains metadata not to be rendered.

Comment: @Rooster It says, render tree contain visible elements. so, it should contain position absolute

Comment: Do you have a link reference to that information? Just curious to see if they elaborate on that point.

Comment: @Michael_B I think, you are correct. For last line (position absolute), I donot have the reference. I read it long back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are reading that information, but `position: absolute` elements are (obviously) rendered.

There are two trees: DOM and CSSOM. Both combine to generate the render tree that builds the page that we see.

According to Google Developers, `display: none` will not render. But there is no indication that `position: absolute` will not render, as well.

> [**Google Developers - Render-tree construction, layout, and
>   paint**](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=en)
>
> *A few salient points from the article:*
>
> - The CSSOM and DOM trees are combined into a render tree, which is then used to compute the layout of ***each visible element*** and serves as
>     an input to the paint process which renders the pixels to screen. *(emphasis mine)*
> - The DOM and CSSOM trees are combined to form the render tree. Render tree contains only the nodes required to render the page.
> - The first step is for the browser to combine the DOM and CSSOM into a “render tree” that captures ***all the visible DOM content*** on the page,
>     plus all the CSSOM style information for each node. *(emphasis mine)*
> - To construct the render tree, the browser roughly does the following:
>
>   - Starting at the root of the DOM tree, traverse each visible node.
>
>     - Some nodes are not visible at all (e.g. script tags, meta tags, and so on), and are omitted since they are not reflected in the
>         rendered output.
>     - Some nodes are hidden via CSS and are also omitted from the render tree - e.g. the span node in example above is missing from the
>         render tree because we have an explicit rule that sets `display: none`
>         property on it.
>   - For each visible node find the appropriate matching CSSOM rules and apply them.
>   - Emit visible nodes with content and their computed styles.
> - The final output is a render that contains both the content and the style information of ***all the visible content on the screen.*** *(emphasis mine)*

Read the full article here: [Render-tree construction, layout, and paint](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=en)